how to run R CMD javareconf in conda environments
on Ubuntu, I have two R versions on my system and use anaconda.

/anaconda/envs/mycondaenv/lib/R/bin/R # 4.4.2, the one I want to configure
/usr/bin/R # used when the default conda env is active

I am trying to install rJava for which I need to sudo -E R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/
The problem is that R CMD javareconf switches me back from mycondaenv to the default conda envir. and when using sudo /anaconda/envs/mycondaenv/lib/R/bin/R CMD javareconf JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 I get the following. how to solve this?
Unable to compile a JNI program, ignoring this though as you may not want to compile anything here
.. this is an Anaconda Distribution and conda-forge customization whereby env activation causes us
.. to call R CMD javareconf in order to dynamically detect a JDK that may be in that env. The fact
.. that we prohibit setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is also somewhat responsible for us needing to do this
.. because ${R_HOME}/etc/ldpaths is the normal way that R dynamically finds shared libraries. This
.. is what would, in upstream R, set LD_LIBRARY_PATH. AD cannot set this as it causes all sorts of
.. issues with DT_RUNPATH / DT_RPATH on various distributions.

